# Transform Data Extension to Triggered Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Does anyone know whether it is possible to transform a standard DE to a triggered send DE?

Comment: There is not a way to transform it, the link in the answer below automates a way to create a new de using the current de as a reference

Answer (score 0):

Ivan Razine just [put out a method for doing this in SSJS on his blog.](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-convert-into-triggeredsend-data-extension-ssjs/) You should find everything you need in that link.